# Evolution of neurons in Neural Network

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I recently started taking a lot of interest in AI, neural networks and GA in particular, and I want to build a small AI to be able to handle a problem.
I researched the subject, and I think I have a good enough understanding at how non growing neural networks work and how their weights evolve, but I couldn't find an explanation about how to determine if the network needs to generate a new neuron, and how many should I start with and such.

P.S.
I'm a computer science student, and programmer by occupation so I have a good understanding of algorithms and graphs, but I didn't study AI just yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A genetic algorithm doesn't 'determine' if a neuron should be added or removed, it does it by a random chance. When it has a positive impact on the performance of the network, it will stay in future generations - survival of the fittest.

The NEAT paper starts with a network that only has input nodes and output nodes. Then it evolves more and more nodes and connections, however by random (`mutationRate`) chance!

[Read about it here](http://nn.cs.utexas.edu/downloads/papers/stanley.ec02.pdf)

[image]

---

I have implemented this in JavaScript, so if you want to see how a network evolves to act as an XOR gate, check [this](https://wagenaartje.github.io/neataptic/articles/evolvexor/#) out. I have also written a Python library ([NeuralFit](https://neuralfit.net/)), if that suits your more.

Answer (score 0):

Starting neuron number is define is hard. Scientisc usually difine this using intuition or gentic algoritm describet upper. If you use first option and the network don't work good:
1. (too many neurons, network fast learn lerning examples but have problems with symilar problems) make new smaller network and learn it.
2. (too litle neurons, network have big error end this can't be smaller during lerning) try to add new neurons too existing network with small weights and continou lerning (connect like others) or make new bigger network and begin new lerning. You can also try add new layers.

input
leyer 1> leyer 2> l 3...

output leyer can be an exception.
use connections all to all
In literature usualy recomentd 3 layers but my experiments told 4 layers have better generalizing.